# How to parametrize a string and replace parameters

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee

I have an String that is entered by the end user, and this string should be of the format `Showing {0} to {1} of {2}` and I would like to replace the parameters in curly brackets with numbers that I compute from the backend.
Exactly like it happens for the strings from the properties file.

 How can I do that?

Sample input:

```
Showing {0} to {1} of {2}
```

Sample output:

```
Showing 1 to 12 of 30
```

Comment: Please show us sample input and output.

Comment: You want the [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class.

Comment: and your code as well

Comment: @Vihar I was looking for something like: String myString="Showing {0} to {1} of {2}"; String result=SomeClass.someStaticMethod(myString,1,12,30);

Comment: As I said.  The class you want is MessageFormat.  It does  _precisely_ what you've asked for.  Go and read up about it.

Comment: Yoou can also have a look at `String.format()`.

Comment: You have only 3 parameters or they are dynamic?

Comment: @daniele then take a look at my answer, that's what you need.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this with [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

```
String userInput = "Showing {0} to {1} of {2}";
String result = MessageFormat.format(userInput, 1, 12, 30);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `String.format()`

Here is how to do that

```
int a = 1;
int b = 12;
int c = 30;
String myFormattedString = String.format("Showing %d to %d of %d", a, b, c); 
// Value of myFormattedString is 'Showing 1 to 12 of 30'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Showing {0} to {1} of {2}";
    int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
    s = s.replaceAll("(.*)(\\d)(.*)(\\d)(.*)(\\d)", "$1" + arr[0] + "$3"
            + arr[1] + "$5" + arr[2]);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

O/P :

```
Showing {10} to {20} of {30}
```

Comment: this should be listed as an example under the definition of "reinventing the wheel".

Answer (score 1):

You could use MessageFormat from java.text.MessageFormat package as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "this is {0} of {1} another String";
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(a, "replacement1", "replacement2"));
    }
```

O/P
"this is replacement1 of replacement2 another String"

Answer (score 0):

you should use a regular expression to get the value of those params.

To do so, you have to consider the following code example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("Showing 1 to 12 of 30");


int[] numbers; 
int i = 0;
while(matcher.find()){
 numbers[i++] = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
}
```

so now you have all those numbers in a int[].

Answer (score 0):

You could String.format if you have multiple params and replacement, although if you just have single param to replace you could rather use

```
String myselfUrl = https://url.abc/{cloudId}/api/myself
StringUtils.replace(myselfUrl, "{cloudId}", 123456);
```

will result in

```
https://url.abc/123456/api/myself
```